SUID бит с меньшими правами
Обычно права у владельца больше, чем у группы или others. Но если такая ситуация сложилась, что типа наоборот, то есть у владельца права 4 (чтение), а у группы, например, 6 (чтение и запись). Будет ли в таком случае SUID ограничивать права группы, когда кто-то из группы попытается получить доступ к файлу&
